# How to print only unique names here in photon network unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I did this but it prints one name multiple times. How do I make sure it prints one name only one at a time:

```
foreach(Player player in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
{
    if(race_entered)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length; i++)
        {
            player_name[i].text = player.NickName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently iterating exponentially. For every player you again iterate all players and overwrite all UI texts with the current player.

What you want is iterating only **once**

```
if(race_entered)
{
    // cache since property access might be expensive
    var players = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;

    // Note btw for iterating collections you always want an index 
    // "< Length" instead of "<= Length"
    for(int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
    {
        var player = players[i];
        player_name[i].text = player.NickName;
    }
}
```